# Fast way of adding fields to a nested dict

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, dictionary, optimization

I need a help with improving my code.
I've got a nested dict with many levels:

```
{
    "11": {
        "FacLC": {
            "immty": [
                "in_mm",
                "in_mm"
            ],
            "moood": [
                "in_oo",
                "in_oo"
            ]
        }
    },
    "22": {
        "FacLC": {
            "immty": [
                "in_mm",
                "in_mm",
                "in_mm"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

And I want to add additional fields on every level, so my output looks like this:

```
[
    {
        "id": "",
        "name": "11",
        "general": [
            {
                "id": "",
                "name": "FacLC",
                "specifics": [
                    {
                        "id": "",
                        "name": "immty",
                        "characteristics": [
                            {
                                "id": "",
                                "name": "in_mm"
                            },
                            {
                                "id": "",
                                "name": "in_mm"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "",
                        "name": "moood",
                        "characteristics": [
                            {
                                "id": "",
                                "name": "in_oo"
                            },
                            {
                                "id": "",
                                "name": "in_oo"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "",
        "name": "22",
        "general": [
            {
                "id": "",
                "name": "FacLC",
                "specifics": [
                    {
                        "id": "",
                        "name": "immty",
                        "characteristics": [
                            {
                                "id": "",
                                "name": "in_mm"
                            },
                            {
                                "id": "",
                                "name": "in_mm"
                            },
                            {
                                "id": "",
                                "name": "in_mm"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I managed to write a 4-times nested for loop, what I find inefficient and inelegant:

```
for main_name, general in my_dict.items():
    generals = []
    for general_name, specific in general.items():
        specifics = []
        for specific_name, characteristics in specific.items():
            characteristics_dicts = []
            for characteristic in characteristics:
                characteristics_dicts.append({
                    "id": "",
                    "name": characteristic,
                })
            specifics.append({
                "id": "",
                "name": specific_name,
                "characteristics": characteristics_dicts,
            })
        generals.append({
            "id": "",
            "name": general_name,
            "specifics": specifics,
        })
    my_new_dict.append({
        "id": "",
        "name": main_name,
        "general": generals,
    })
```

I am wondering if there is more compact and efficient solution.

Answer (score 1):

In the past I created a function to do it. Basically you call this function everytime that you need to add new fields to a nested dict, independently on how many levels this nested dict have. You only have to inform the 'full path' , that I called the 'key_map'.
Like ['node1','node1a','node1apart3']

```
def insert_value_using_map(_nodes_list_to_be_appended, _keys_map, _value_to_be_inserted):
    for _key in _keys_map[:-1]:
        _nodes_list_to_be_appended = _nodes_list_to_be_appended.setdefault(_key, {})
    _nodes_list_to_be_appended[_keys_map[-1]] = _value_to_be_inserted
```